# Why would one not want their probability space's sigma algebra to be the power set?

Tags: probability-theory

Let $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P)$ be a probability space.  It seems like we would want to be able to measure the probability of each $\omega \in \Omega$, for which we must require that each $\{\omega\} \in \mathcal{F}$ as well.  But this implies $\mathcal{F} = \mathcal{P}(\Omega)$ if $\Omega$ is countable, at least.  If it is not, I have the following question either way:

Is there a good example of why we would desire $\mathcal{F} \neq \mathcal{P}(\Omega)$?

Comment: "But this implies ${\cal F} = {\cal P}(\Omega)$."  No it doesn't.  A $\sigma$-algebra only needs to be closed under *countable* unions.

Comment: One reason maybe that for uncountable sets, the power set becomes two large.

Comment: If you believe in the Axiom of Choice, it is not possible to assign a consistent measure to all subsets of $\Omega$ if $\operatorname{card}(\Omega)$ is large enough. See [Vitali sets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vitali_set)

Comment: @mjqxxxx Thanks for noticing, good point.  I edited it.

Comment: Keyword: Filtrations.